# Flutter: Exception not firing when Image.file load fails

Tags: image, file, flutter, exception

I'm trying to load the image `employerPic` from device memory.  This photo may not exist, so it should fallback to an Avatar.  Logcat throws this error:

> Unhandled Exception: FileSystemException: Cannot retrieve length of
> file, path =
> '/data/user/0/uk.co.neighbourly/app_flutter/MYjFq4FFKKiayOl03sdX.jpg'
> (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

Basically, I've given flutter a file path, however the file doesn't exist in this instance. I've encased this whole attempt in a try{} block so I can fall back to an Exception.  You can see I've used 2 Exceptions, a `on FileSystemException` & then a general `catch(error){}`, But when the `try` clause fails neither gets fired.  What!

I'd love a solution, or a more elegant way to code an image fallback to a guaranteed image.

```
if(_appDocsDir != null) {
  File employerPic = _getEmployerPicFile();
  if(employerPic != null) {
    print('JOB TILE: GOT IMAGE FROM DEVICE! path: ${employerPic.path}');
    try {
      profilePic = ClipOval(
        child: Image.file(
            employerPic, width: 60, height: 60, fit: BoxFit.cover),
      );
    } on FileSystemException {
      print(LOG + 'failed to load profilePic from mem, attempting Avatar');
      profilePic = Image.asset(
          PersonUtils.getAvatarFromId[widget._job.avatar], fit: BoxFit.cover);
    } catch(error) {
      print(LOG + '!Strange! error when attempting to load employerPhoto: $error');
    };
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your current solution should work except that you need to rearrange the code.
The code to get the `employerPic` File object should be in the try block so that when it fails the catch block can run.

You should update the code to look like this:

```
if(_appDocsDir != null) {
    try {
      File employerPic = _getEmployerPicFile();
      if(employerPic != null) {
         print('JOB TILE: GOT IMAGE FROM DEVICE! path: ${employerPic.path}');
      }
      profilePic = ClipOval(
        child: Image.file(
            employerPic, width: 60, height: 60, fit: BoxFit.cover),
      );
    } on FileSystemException {
      print(LOG + 'failed to load profilePic from mem, attempting Avatar');
      profilePic = Image.asset(
          PersonUtils.getAvatarFromId[widget._job.avatar], fit: BoxFit.cover);
    } catch(error) {
      print(LOG + '!Strange! error when attempting to load employerPhoto: $error');
    };
    
  }
```

Comment: I've modified my code, then tried just copying yours, it runs, but throws this:
Exception caught by image resource service:  
The following FileSystemException was thrown resolving an image codec:
Cannot open file, path = '/data/user/0/uk.co.neighbourly/app_flutter/MYjFq4FFKKiayOl03sdX.jpg' (OS Error: No such file or directory, errno = 2)

I presume basically the Exception is caught by Image.file, somehow, although I can't see it in its code.  Hummph!  Thanks for your attention Victor.

Answer (score 0):

Well that approach didn't work.  In the end I setup the default Avatar image which I can rely on in `build()` a wrinkle being I have to test it hasn't been assigned with a photo already.

I attempt to get a profile PHOTO from my `init()` method, I call this function:

```
  void initialiseLocalStorage() async {
    _appDocsDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

    if (_appDocsDir != null) {
      String pathName =
      p.join(_appDocsDir.path, "${widget._job.employerId.trim()}" + ".jpg");
      var fileExists = await io.File(pathName).exists();
      if (fileExists) {
        print(LOG + 'profile photo on device! $pathName');
        setState(() {
          profilePic = ClipOval(
              child: Image.file(
                  File(pathName), width: 60, height: 60, fit: BoxFit.cover));
        });
        return;
      }
      else {
        print(LOG + 'profile photo not on device, keep Avatar');
        return;
      }
    } else print(LOG + 'Error _appDocsDir == $_appDocsDir so can\'t load');
  }
```

Seems to do the job alright.

LEARNING: I think Flutter's image error handling removes some ways of solving issues, channeling you to try to do all computation in `async` functions called from `init()`.